# Modulo of sum of big numbers

Tags: c++, math

Well, I need to calculate modulo 10^9+7 of next number:
2^(n-1)+2(n-2)+...+2(n-p)
where values are:
n<=5000
p<=5000
So basicly, the highest possible number would be:
2^(4999)+2^(4998)+...+2^0
Here's what I've tried, but I guess it's not enough to cover this big number.

```
long long power(int x,int n)//calculates (x^n) % 10^9+7
{
    long long sol=1;
    long long b=x;
    while(n){
        if(n&1==1){
            sol*=b;
            sol%=1000000007;
        }
        n>>=1;
        b*=b;
        b%=1000000007;
    }
    return sol;
}

 long long calculate(int n,int p){//calculates 2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)+...+2^(n-p)
    long long ret=power(2,n-1);p-=1;
    while(p--!=0)
        ret=(ret%1000000007+(ret/2)%1000000007)%1000000007;
    return ret;
}
```

This code should calculate modulo of every 2^(n-someNumber) and then, sum all of modulos %10^9+7 in order to get final number.
I'm not so good with big numbers, so please help.
Will this code cover even the case with highest possible number?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: No. Hint: `(x+y) mod z == ((x mod z)+(y mod z) mod z)`.

Comment: that's what I did, didn't I? @EJP

Comment: No, it isn't what you did. You added all the numbers, which will overflow, and then took the modulus. The equation shows how to avoid the overflow. You have to take the modulus after every addition.

Comment: `power` could return just `long` (since 10^9 < 2^31). Although `sol` needs the extra precision.

Comment: I changed the code, is it ok now? @EJP

Comment: `ret = (ret+ ret/2) % 1000000007` would be sufficient, since you know `ret` is always less than the modulus.

Comment: right, thanks! @Alan Stokes

Comment: Simplest is to algebraically transform sum of 2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)+...+2^(n-p) into 2^n-2^p. Then use [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) transform [2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)+...+2^(n-p)]% (10^9+7)=(2^n-2^p)% (10^9+7)=2^n% (10^9+7)-2^p(% 10^9+7) Thus 2^p% m is cycling (Primitive root modulo n)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n] calculate this cycle and then can reduce power p in 2^p by cycling! Thus you can calculate your expression in ANY values of n and p without overflowing

Comment: excuse me some mistake2^n-2^p change to 2^n-2^(n-p) 
everywhere
Last expression must 2^n% (10^9+7)-2^(n-p)(% 10^9+7)